# How to install a specific Debian/Ubuntu release version?

Tags: debian, debootstrap

I am investigating reproducible builds and would like for that to end up with a script that sets up a *constant* VM image containing my build environment. For now, I'll put aside issues with timestamps and other sources of differences, so by "*constant*", I mean a reproducible environment. I am aware of the Debian [ReproducibleBuilds](https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/BuildinfoFiles) effort, which puts a requirement on **package versions** to guarantee an identical build. I want something similar, but at the **system** level.

I started with Alpine, which lets me create a VM based on a [specific release](https://github.com/alpinelinux/alpine-make-vm-image/blob/master/example/repositories) very easily.

How would I do the same for Debian, which provides for example *stretch* releases 9.0 to 9.4?

The best I could come up with so far was the following: I had a look at the [release changelog](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/ChangeLog), then used the closest [snapshot](http://snapshot.debian.org/) as my package source for *debootstrap*.

```
$ wget -q -O- http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/ChangeLog | grep "Debian.*released"
Sat, 10 Mar 2018 - Debian 9.4 released
Sat, 09 Dec 2017 - Debian 9.3 released
Sat, 07 Oct 2017 - Debian 9.2 released
Sat, 22 Jul 2017 - Debian 9.1 released
Sat, 17 Jun 2017 - Debian 9.0 released
$ # Looking at release 9.2
$ wget -q -O- "http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/?year=2017&month=10" | html2text | sed -e 's/[:-]//g' -e 's/_/T/g' | awk '/20171007/ {print "http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/"$1"Z/"}'
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171007T032909Z/
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171007T103908Z/
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171007T213914Z/
$ mkdir -p chroot_stretch_20171007T103908Z
$ sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 --variant=minbase stretch chroot_stretch_20171007T103908Z http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171007T103908Z/
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Retrieving Release 
I: Retrieving Release.gpg 
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id 067E3C456BAE240ACEE88F6FEF0F382A1A7B6500)
I: Retrieving Packages 
(...)
$ find -maxdepth 1 -name "chroot_stretch_2017100*" | sort | while read d; do echo $d; cat $d/etc/debian_version; sudo chroot $d apt-cache policy | grep stretch; echo ""; done
./chroot_stretch_20171006T213452Z
9.1
 500 http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171006T213452Z stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.1,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64

./chroot_stretch_20171007T032909Z
9.1
 500 http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171007T032909Z stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.1,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64

./chroot_stretch_20171007T103908Z
9.1
 900 http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171007T103908Z stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.2,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64

./chroot_stretch_20171007T213914Z
9.1
 500 http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171007T213914Z stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.2,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64

./chroot_stretch_20171008T032534Z
9.1
 500 http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171008T032534Z stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.2,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
```

As we can see, the release tag from *apt-cache policy* changes between two snapshots of the same day. However */etc/debian_version* doesn't get updated, even though looking at the [base-file package versions](http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/base-files/) shows a new version is made available. Note that there is no explicit snapshot taken upon a release, so this approach is a "best effort" one. Consequently, there are multiple ways of defining what Debian release 9.2 actually is.

I don't really see the point of dot releases if there isn't a simple way of targeting them, so I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more web digging, I found a thread on the Debian user list on the same topic: *[Restrict apt to specific Jessie distro](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2016/02/msg00361.html)* ([google copy](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/linux.debian.user/Wv0pURbcNJM/discussion)). This [particular post](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2016/02/msg00377.html) gives a lengthy answer, also relying on the Debian snapshots.

<del>What is still missing is a snapshot clearly associated to a point release, but any will do for my purpose.</del>

To link an official release to a snapshot, one can use the information from the jigdo files that let you rebuild an official ISO:

```
$ wget -q -O - https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/8.10.0/amd64/jigdo-bd/debian-8.10.0-amd64-BD-1.jigdo | gunzip | awk -F= '/snapshot.debian.org/ {print $2}'
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171209T215122Z/
```